# Adding a custom/relate field in Email template in Sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created a custom module named surveys which will be in many to many relationship with targets. I need to insert survey name while sending campaign mails to targets.

Currently I managed to populate survey module entities in insert variable by following the guide from [adding a custom module in insert variable dropdownlist](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f3/adding-custom-module-insert-variable-dropdownlist-email-template-50158/) in email template but the issue is it will never parse the survey name and displays $survey_name in emails that are delivered.

Any help/guidance to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the answer to that forum. The sugarCrm EmailTemplate modules basically is a lot of code to get just few beans working (Accounts, Contacts, Leads, Users, Prospects), I get some templates working with other beans with this steps, this code is based on SugarCrm 6.0.2, class modules/Email.php details on the forum:

1) Let the Email.php create the own bean. Example: LOC510

```
if (... $_REQUEST['parent_type'] == 'Prospects' || TRUE)
```

2) Create an array of replace fields. Example: LOC521

```
  foreach($bean->field_defs as $key => $field_def) {
    $replace_fields ['$'.strtolower(get_class($bean).'_'.$field_def['name'])] 
    = $bean->$field_def['name'];
    //example of fieldnames: $bug_name, $bug_type, $case_date_created, $case_name, etc...
  }
```

3) Replace the fields on html template. Example: LOC545

```
$this->description_html = str_replace(array_keys($replace_fields), $replace_fields, $this->description_html);
```

3) Replace the fields on txt template. Example: LOC549

```
$this->description = str_replace(array_keys($replace_fields), $replace_fields, $this->description);
```